# Equivalence of statements regarding operator norm.

Tags: calculus, normed-spaces

Let $(V,\left\Vert \cdot\right\Vert_V),(W,\left\Vert \cdot\right\Vert_W) $ be norm spaces.

For any linear transformation $\;T:V\rightarrow W\;$ we will define:$\;\left\Vert T\right\Vert _{op}=sup\{\left\Vert Tv\right\Vert _{W}:\left\Vert v\right\Vert _{V}=1\}$

Show that the following are equivalent:

1. $T$ is continuous
2. $T$ is continuous in $0_v$
3. $\;\left\Vert T\right\Vert _{op} < \infty $

I want to show this by proving $1 \implies 2 \implies 3 \implies 1 $

$1 \implies 2 \;$ is given.

I would love to get a hint / insight on how to do $ 2 \implies 3 \implies 1 $

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** Showing $1\iff 2$ and $1\iff 3$ would be easier.

$2\implies 1$: Use the linearity of $T$: we can see that by translation that the continuity of $T$ at $0$ implies that of any point.

$1\implies 3$: $v\mapsto \|Tv\|$ is continuous, and every continuous function over a closed set has a maximum.

$3\implies 1$: You can show that $\|Tx\|\le\|T\|\|x\|$: Could you see that why $\|Tx/\|x\|\|\le \|T\|$ holds?

Comment: Thanks for your insight, I would love to see how to do $2 \implies 3 $ tho.
Also I didn't quite get your observation on $2\implies 1$ and $3\implies 1$.
Mind elaborating?

Comment: @vpam I’ll try it later, I was sleeping and am on outside.